# KDB port gets reset after closing the current session

Tags: kdb

I am working with KDB database with version KDB+ 4.0. I can see in the kx docs that we can set the port using following command:

```
\p 5000
```

This sets the port on 5000. But once I close the KDB terminal, the port gets reset on 0i and all the tables and data created in the KDB with port 5000 vanishes.

Does anybody knows how to set the port so that it remains as it is for every session till I don't change it?

Answer (score 3):

Add `-p 5000` to the start command of your q session.

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/listening-port/